# How to know whether i have clicked the particular link in the next page

Tags: php

I have created certain links using a `for` loop in PHP.

```
foreach($storage as $val)
{
    if($val!="")
    {
        echo "$val";
        echo "<a href=\"b.html\">Link</a>";
    }
}
```

Page will look like

```
content1      Link to b.html
content2      Link to b.html
content3      Link to b.html
content4      Link to b.html
...
...
```

In the next page I want to retrieve the correct content based on the link clicked.
Example: If I click the second link the content to be retrieved is "content2".

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Some suggestions: 1) `echo "$val";` is crap. You don't need quotes - you just want to echo the variable. 2) You can quote using `"` or `'`. Use whatever is necessary so you do not have to escape quotes, in your case: `echo '<a href="b.html">Link</a>'`

Answer (score 2):

Create your links like that:

```
echo '<a href="b.html?content=' . $val . '">Link</a>'
```

Then, on the other page, use this code:

```
$content = isset($_GET['content']) ? $_GET['content'] : '';
```

Then `$content` contains whatever was passed in the URL - or an empty string if the param was missing.

Answer (score 1):

You could set Get parameters so that your links are to b.html?var=content2

Then you can just read the Get Parameters

```
 echo $val ."<a href=\"b.html?var=". $val ."\">Link</a>";
```

and you can then view this value with

```
echo $_GET['var'];
```

Comment: You mean GET parameters? POST is not sent via the URL.

Comment: Jea of course it should be get, as you cant send post via normal link (without jquery or sth)